# Is there a way to treat fields as @Transient in a configurable way?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

We have a Database not owned by us, it deploys to production only after performance testing and CR requirements, etc, and it is a bottle neck. Lower environments don't have the same restrictions.

When making model changes, our code base is ready for production well before the DB, and can't be deployed until the DB is ready, otherwise new columns included in `SELECT` or `INSERT` queries will not exist and cause errors. This causes a holding pattern, general headaches, etc.

Fortunately, `@Transient` works perfectly to unblock prod, but it would be deployed to all environments. Ideally, we could make that behaviour configurable so for example only production would treat those fields as `@Transient`

```
@Getter
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "INCOME", schema = "dbo")
public class Income {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = INCOME_ID)
    private long incomeId;

    @Column(name = RELATED_ID, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Transient
    private Long relatedId;
```

Any suggestions or possible approaches?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is extracting your datamodel to a separate jar so it can be built and deployed to match your database. Then you can use your build (maven, gradle, etc) to pull the correct version through configuration.  So long as you're coding to an interface and/or method signatures don't change, it should work.

Comment: This sounds really dangerous. It means that the most central code (the model) is not really tested as it runs differently in test and production. Shudder... I would wait for the DB before deploying a new model every time. You could deploy the other parts provided that they can work with an older model, though. Perhaps having a slow release cycle for the model and a quicker for the rest of the application is good enough?

Comment: Are you sure a hacky technical solution is the best way to solve this problem? Why don't you contact a relevant higher up and tell them that they're spending a load of money because the DB process is making expensive developers waste their time.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of using [xml mapping](https://thorben-janssen.com/mapping-definitions-jpa-hibernate-annotations-xml/). In your case it will look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<entity-mappings xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd"
                 version="2.1">

    <entity class="package.name.Income">
        <attributes>
           <transient name="relatedId"/>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```