# Spring Data JPA/Hibernate - is it possible to have a column that optionally exists in the database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a database that is being upgraded to add a column to an existing table. However, I would like to make the Springboot service interacting with the database backwards compatible with the older version of the database without the new column. The Springboot service would be upgraded to have the new column in the Entity but I would like it to interact with either version of the database. Is there a way to prevent the service from failing if the new column in the Entity does not exist in the database?

I researched around and was not able to find a viable solution as of yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72103741/3426309